# How efficient is the "with" statement?

Tags: javascript, performance

It is hard to Google for some keywords like "with" word, so I am testing to ask here.

Is the with statement in JavaScript inefficient?

For instance, say I have:

```
with(obj3) {
     with(obj2) {
         with(obj1) {
               with(obj0) {
                    eval("(function() { console.log(aproperty) })();");
               }
         }
     }
}
```

Would the above be more or less efficient, if for instance, I walked over obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3 and merged them together, and then used either:

1. One with statement alone
2. Created a **parameters string** with the keys of obj0, obj1, obj2 and obj3, and an **args** array for the values and used:

   ```
   eval("function fn(aproperty, bproperty) { console.log(aproperty); }")
   fn.apply(undefined, args);
   ```

Which of these three approaches can be deemed to be quicker? I am guessing on with statements but so many with's makes me think I can optimize it further.

Comment: It varies by browser. Which ones do you support?

Comment: You should probably not use the with statement: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Comment: All browsers so the average. I am thinking generally.

Comment: It's not a question of performance but readability and maintainability.

Comment: @RBZ I have my reasons :)

Comment: "ALL BROWSERS"? Good luck.

Comment: @Juhana Well this is an API call so performance goes first here :)

Comment: Wow, both `with` and `eval`. It's like Crockford's worst nightmare. ;-D

Comment: No, it doesn't. I mean, you can micro-optimize all you want, but in practice it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I don't think this is a great approach, but it shouldn't get downvoted for not being best practice - the question is well-expressed, and I'd be interested in the answer.

Comment: just do `console.log(obj3.obj2.obj1.obj0);` and have done with it.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: I half agree with you. If the question is ultimately about performance, then IMO, it's really not a good question, since it really just depends on the implementation. And if OP wants the average of all browsers, then that's even worse.

Comment: Also, for all of the folks who think this is ridiculous, it's worth noting that [Underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template) use this exact approach.

Comment: @BlueSkies - yes, this may vary by browser, but there are often clear performance benefits to one approach or another in JS, as in any other language. You can't discount a question just because it asks about JS performance.

Comment: @nrabinowitz ridicilous is the people who think they know what they are talking about and refuse to focus on the question instead. I am writing an template engine so thank you :) But this is a recurrent thing on all forums, that people always think they know better than you. I am using this because I need it, and there is no other way... but try explaining that in words that will be accepted.

Comment: PS. I am writing a jsperf test so we will soon find out with you folks help

Comment: Why didn't you just write a test to start with? That should be the first thing you do.

Comment: @BlueSkies I didn't formulate the question until I did, plus I need people to contribute to the test statistics and run it on several machines :)

Comment: Here is the test. Please run it on your machines :) 

http://jsperf.com/withstatement

Comment: Sorry folks, I had missed that I didn't invoke the methods in the last edit. Try again: 

http://jsperf.com/withstatement

The winner seems to be many evals :)

Comment: Why would any browser-maker still focus on a deprecated and in `"use strict"`-mode even fully *dead* `with` statement (regardless of 'considered harmful'-articles (that for once aren't nitpicking) or Crockford's feelings)? Don't get me wrong, I'm usually king old-school reliability. If you'd say, reverse while *should* be faster then reverse for, you are right (although it is not the *current* reality..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer browsers have an internal tokening mechanism to make the javascript interpretation cheaper. It is very like JIT in the newer JVMs. I think there isn't a much problem with your deeply embedded with-s, practically it will be some like

```
__get_aproperty() {
    if (obj0.has("aproperty")) return obj0.aproperty;
    if (obj1.has("aproperty")) return obj1.aproperty;
    if (obj2.has("aproperty")) return obj2.aproperty;
    if (obj3.has("aproperty")) return obj3.aproperty;
}
```

So, the structure of your js is highly embedded, but the structure of the real execution in the JS-engine of the browsers, will be simple and linear.

But the tokenization of the JS, that is costly. And if the JS-engine finds an eval, needs to tokenize.

I voted for the first version.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although they appeared to be very equal: 

http://jsperf.com/withstatement

Comment: By me too, although the nomany won (by me too). But this eval was simple. Maybe the JS-Engine could somehow avoid the repetitive tokenization of this js. Maybe adding a "//"+Math.rand() to the evaled string made the difference more visible. Congratulations for the test!

Comment: no... sorry, I had written the code but forgot to actually run it, so it was just method declarations :S ... here it is again :)

http://jsperf.com/withstatement

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed in that the "no with" version uses direct eval which has exactly same problem as with statement since it causes dynamic scoping

Comment: @Esailija I am not sure what you mean, what is the fix for the test then?

Comment: @MoJS not using constructs such as with and eval which make the language dynamically scoped

Comment: @Esailija I am not sure what you are talking about, I want the dynamic scoping. The question was, what is the cheapest way to get there.

Comment: @MoJS no, whatever it is that you want, is not dynamic scoping. Dynamic scoping is one horrible way to implement what you want. It will make even trivial code execute 50x slower.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for options, then you may want to consider a third approach, which would be to create (on the fly if needed) a prototype chain of objects.

---

***EDIT:** My solution was broken. It requres the non-standard `__proto__` property. I'm updating to fix it, but be aware that this isn't supported in all environments.*

---

```
var objs = [null,obj3,obj2,obj1,obj0];

for (var i = 1; i < objs.length; i++) {
    objs[i].__proto__ = Object.create(objs[i-1]);
}

var result = objs.pop();
```

This avoids `with` and should be quicker than merging, though only testing will tell.

---

And then if all you needed was a product of certain properties, this will be very quick.

```
var props = ["x2","b1","a3"];
var product = result.y3;

for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
    product *= result[props[i]];
```

Comment: I will consider using Function but I am bit sure what the first part is for, where do you use result then? 

here is the test ( but without yours ) 

http://jsperf.com/withstatement

Comment: @MoJS: The result would be like your merged object, except there's no merge. Just a prototype chain of objects. The first object in the chain will be an empty object, so you could actually add properties without affecting the others. The next object is `obj0`, followed by `obj1`, etc. So when you look up a property, it'll look for it in the order of `first > obj0 > obj1 > obj2 > obj3`. So let's say the property `foo` is on `obj1` and `obj3`. You'll get the value from `obj1` because it shadows the same property on `obj3`.

Comment: @MoJS: I must say though that I don't understand the purpose of the function in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really either ... but the last one does invoke a function so to really compare them the other ones should declare and invoke a method too. I had incorrectly written the test earlier and forgot to invoke the methods. try again: http://jsperf.com/withstatement

Comment: Regarding the new Function() ... unless you walk over the properties, you won't actually get the parameters for the Function ... with eval this is not neccessary. and there is no obj.getKeys() right?

Comment: @MoJS: Sorry, my approach is messed up. I need to delete it. But WRT the function, why wouldn't you just iterate a list of the properties you want, and incrementally create the product of those properties?

Comment: The question is whch approach is quicker.. I need to write another test :S

Comment: @MoJS: I instead updated my answer to use a non-standard syntax. Won't work in all browsers, but may be interesting. I also updated your test. This one is by far the fastest, but again has limited support. http://jsperf.com/withstatement/2

Comment: I saw your test, but it implements this specific case where I multiply. I am writing my own, but it is tricky to call new Function with an array ...

Comment: @MoJS: With `new Function()` you'd just define a parameter for the Array, then pass it.

Comment: yeah, i was doing it a bit wrong ... updated the test case to include that: 

http://jsperf.com/withstatement

Answer (score 0):

With statement will make your code run like it's 1980 - literally every optimization implemented in a JIT cannot be used when it's in effect.